# De-serialize JSON return empty data

Tags: json, datacontractjsonserializer

I use api url to get json response

```
http://localhost/WaWebService/Json/NodeDetail/Demo/SCADA_NODE_DEMO
```

Using `Postman` software I verify there is response

```
{
    "Result": {
        "Ret": 0
    },
    "Node": {
        "ProjectId": 1,
        "NodeId": 1,
        "NodeName": "SCADA_NODE_DEMO",
        "Description": "",
        "Address": "SALMAN-MUSHTAQ",
        "Port1": 0,
        "Port2": 0,
        "Timeout": 0
    }
}
```

After it I make class

```
class Result
    {
        public int Ret { get; set; }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int NodeId { get; set; }
        public string NodeName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int Port1 { get; set; }
        public int Port2 { get; set; }
        public int Timeout { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I de-serialize the json object using `DataContractJsonSerializer`

```
var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password") };


                string json = client.DownloadString(url);
                using(var ms = new MemoryStream (Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
                {
                    DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Node));
                    Node nObj = (Node)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);
                    Console.WriteLine("Node name: " + nObj.NodeName);
                }
```

It gives nothing on console. Please help to solve this issue. Advance thanks.

Comment: I also try with Json.Net and JavaScriptSerializer, but same problem I faced. Please help experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create class that have same structure as response json

```
class JsonResponse
{
    public Result Result { get; set; }
    public Node Node { get; set; }
}

class Result
{
    public int Ret { get; set; }
}

public class Node
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Port1 { get; set; }
    public int Port2 { get; set; }
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
}
```

And then de-serialize json like this

```
DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonResponse));
```