# Deserialize JSON to fit Model

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My JSON string looks like the following:

`"[{\r\n\t'variable1': [{0:'somename'}],\r\n\r\n\t'variable2': 'xxx'\r\n}]"`

I want to de-serialize this `JSON` string so it fits my `Model` which is shown below:

```
    public string variable2 { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> variable1 { get; set; }
```

However, the `array` part (`variable1`) of the `JSON` string doesn't get deserialize. It detects the `int` but, the string 'somename' doesn't get detected. It just shows null.

How can I solve this ?

Note: I am using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Is that valid json?

Comment: Yes. JSON validators says so.

Comment: i think the problem is with `KeyValuePair`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [De-serialize JSON return empty data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294262/de-serialize-json-return-empty-data)

Comment: It's not valid Json. Paste it on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com and you'll find that it's not valid for several reasons

Comment: JSON Editor Online also calls it valid. i think he needs a wrapper.

Comment: JSONList says its valid.

Comment: Used 2 online tools and in both returned json as invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably depends on which library you're using to deserialize your JSON. If you are using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), I would also suggest changing your `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` to just `Dictionary<int, string>`, doing so will likely solve your deserialization issues.

Comment: Any other workaround where I could still use `KeyValuePair`

Comment: If you want to go that route, you're going to start feeling the pain very fast. Keep in mind that a Dictionary is a collection of KeyValuePair, you can use the IEnumerable interface to enumerate over them just like you would the List. Knowing that, and if you still want to keep your list, then you can learn about creating your own JSON converters: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 1):

The easies way to parse this json would be like this:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldParseClass()
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SOClass>>("[{\r\n\t'variable1': [{0:'somename'}],\r\n\r\n\t'variable2': 'xxx'\r\n}]");
    Assert.True(result.First().variable1[0]["0"] == "somename");
}
public class SOClass
{
    public string variable2 { get; set; }
    public List<dynamic> variable1 { get; set; }
}
```

The main problem in your Json is `varible1` beening a list. All values should be on the same object to be a dictionary. 
On the oder hand, if you wanted an KeyValuePair list, you should pass those items like so `{'key':0,'value':'somename'}`.

Comment: So, will there be any issue if I continue to use KeyValue pair instead of a Dictionary later on ? What do you recommend ?

Comment: They aren't interchangeable solutions. It meas that Their Json structure are different. Furthermore your Json is something else, thats why I used dynamic.

Comment: Dictionary on Json: `{variable1:{'0':'somename','0':'othername'}}`
Pair value list on Json: `{variable1:[{'key':'0':'somename'},{'key':'0','value':'othername'}]}`

Answer (score 0):

You should define a custom converter if you have no control over the json:

```
public class Data
{
    public string variable2 { get; set; }

    // pick one: dictionart should be favored, unless you have no-unique keys

//  [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomListKvpConverter<int, string>))]
//  public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> variable1 { get; set; }
//
//  [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDictionaryKvpConverter<int, string>))]
//  public Dictionary<int, string> variable1 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomListKvpConverter<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter<List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>>
{
    public override List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JArray.Load(reader)
            .ToObject<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>[]>()
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .ToList();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class CustomDictionaryKvpConverter<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public override Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JArray.Load(reader)
            .ToObject<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>[]>()
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```